# How to call the ansible play recursively based on until condition

Tags: json, recursion, ansible

I'm trying to execute a playbook recursively until the condition satisfies. But, I couldn't achieve it some-how. Can anyone suggest me the solution.

Ansible-version: 2.2.1.0

Here is my test-plays.

main_play.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Wait till you get the needed thing in the get call
    include: loop.yml
```

Here is the loop.yml

```
- name: Wait until migration jobs reach DbcAllJobxxxxx
  uri:
    url: "http://<url->/jobs"
    method: GET
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json"
      Postman-Token: "31d6"
      cache-control: "no-cache"
    return_content: yes
  register: migration_status
  ignore_errors: yes

- debug: msg="{{ migration_status }}"

#write mig-status to file
- copy: content="{{ migration_status.content }}" dest=/path/to/dest/migration_status.json

- name: Get the DbcAllJobxxxxx status from py script
  shell: python jsonrc.py /path/to/dest/migration_status.json
  register: pyout

- debug: msg="{{ pyout.stdout }}"

- include: loop.yml
  when: pyout.stdout != '1'
  ignore_errors: yes

- debug: msg="{{ pyout.stdout }}"
```

Requirement : GET json call will return json. The json may vary time-to-time as it returns dynamic status. So, want to pool the json data continuously to know the value of a key - Which is a sign to call other event. So, I need to wait for the key-value pair in that json. [It may loss within time frame.. Need to catch at that point]. To achieve same parsing the json through python script and catching the return of pyscript and checking the value and calling the same play if it doesn't satisfy the condition.

Executing `ansible-playbook main_play.yml`

Even the `pyout.stdout == '1'` it's still throwing `ERROR! Unexpected Exception: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error. Did I miss any ?? Help me in this regard.

BTW, I tried to achieve this with `until` using `json_query`. but, parsing become difficult in this part. So, avoided this solution.

Answer (score 1):

From ansible 2.4 onwards there is the `include_tasks` builtin that does work recursively.

main_play.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      counter: 1
  - include_tasks: loop.yml
```

loop.yml:

```
- set_fact:
    counter: "{{counter | int + 1 }}"

- debug: msg="{{ counter }}"

- include_tasks: loop.yml
  when: counter | int < 5
```

Result:

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
included: loop.yml for localhost

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "2"
}

TASK [include_tasks] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: loop.yml for localhost

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "3"
}

TASK [include_tasks] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: loop.yml for localhost

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "4"
}

TASK [include_tasks] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: loop.yml for localhost

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "5"
}

TASK [include_tasks] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=14   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is to loop recursivley until I get the right message or it reaches MAX retries (In case just set very high)

```
- name: Group of tasks that are tightly coupled
  block:

    - name: Increment the retry count
      set_fact:
        retry_count: "{{ 0 if retry_count is undefined else retry_count | int + 1 }}"

    - name: get state file {{ retry_count }}
      command:
        cmd: cat /tmp/test.txt
      register: out


    - debug:
        msg: "Found END message"
      when: "'END' in out.stdout_lines"

    - fail:
       msg: "END not reached"
      when: "not 'END' in out.stdout_lines"

  rescue:

    - fail:
        msg: Maximum retries of grouped tasks reached
      when: retry_count | int == 15

    - name: pause a moment
      pause:
        seconds: 1
      when: "not 'END' in out.stdout_lines"

    - debug:
        msg: "hasen't finished yet, retry"
      when: "not 'END' in out.stdout_lines"

    - include_tasks: loop_control.yml
      when: "not 'END' in out.stdout_lines"
```

Answer (score -1):

It's obvious, I think.

```
"Here is the loop.yml"

...
- include: loop.yml
```

> ERROR! Unexpected Exception: maximum recursion depth exceeded error.